# source files at 1.4 level and j test classes at 1.5 POM updates

Tags: java, maven

I am writing some unit tests to legacy code and it's in java 1.4 compiler settings.

However I am writing my unit tests using powermock/easymock/junit4 etc...which needs 1.5

The project uses a parent pom which states the source and target is 1.4
I am trying to override the following parent pom settings in the project as follows:

```
<build> 
    <plugins>   
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testSource>1.5</testSource>
                <testTarget>1.5</testTarget>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However still, it shows compile errors in my test files as annotations can only be used with JRE 1.5

Here are the parent pom settings:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <source>1.4</source>
                <target>1.4</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Is there any other settings to override??